# Text in a bound asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I have an asp.net page in a VS2010 project.  I've bound the page to a dataset, and I have a line in the front end which looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInCommon" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NumInterests") %>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Works perfect.

Now, what I want to do is append the word "Interests" to the label.  So, I tried this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInCommon" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NumInterests") %> Interests'>
</asp:Label>
```

Doesn't like it.  So I tried this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInCommon" runat="server" Text="'<%#Eval("NumInterests") %>' Interests">
</asp:Label>
```

Doesn't like that either.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?  I'm at the point where I'm ready to just put 2 labels back-to-back, but I have to believe this is possible to do in the same label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInCommon" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NumInterests") + "Interests" %>' >
```

Inside <%# %> is basically just evaluated code so you can treat it as such and even do things like call functions.

Comment: *facepalm*  I can't believe I blew that one.  :oP  Thanks!